# Map<String, ?> how to use it

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

I need to use a Map in java in which '?' can be any type of value, like integer, boolean, long, and so on. This is what I have:

```
Map<String, ?> prefs = Preferences.GetPrefs();

// Now I would like to use it to add new values...
prefs.put("Hi", true); // <-- error
```

How can I use it? Thanks

Comment: What is the return type of Preferences.GetPrefs()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Object

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = Preferences.GetPrefs();
```

then to fetch

```
Boolean result = (Boolean)prefs.get("Hi");
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but to do that I have to cast the GetPrefs() and it works for the 'put' functin but not for the 'get'. Apparently it does not know how to get the values.

Comment: That cast doesn't work. You have to use: Boolean.valueOf((String)prefs.get("Hi"));

Answer (score 5):

You may not call any method on `prefs` which involves the second generic type argument because that type is unknown in your context. The intention behind the `Map<String ?>` return type is "this map should not be mutated by the caller".

You should read `Map<String, ?>` as not a definite type, which it isn't, but as a *template* against which definite types are matched. Specifically, `Map<String, ?>` stands for "any such map which has `String`-typed keys". For example `Map<String, Integer>` matches this template and can be assigned to your variable. Clearly, you are not allowed to put a `String` value to such a map.

If your `GetPrefs` method is fixed, then your only recourse is to force an *unchecked cast* into a definite generic type `Map<String,Object>`, losing type safety.

Otherwise, if you are in control of the `Preferences` class, change the return type of that method to `Map<String, Object>`, if that makes sense for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

The thing about the `?` is that it means that the collection has a type, but we don't know what it is.  That means we can't put any values in the collection, as they might not match the (unknown) collection type.

Consider this code as an example of why:

```
Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, ?> b = a;
a.put("bar", "baz"); // This is fine: Normal use
b.put("foo", 25); // This won't compile

String baz = a.get("bar"); // Returns the string "baz"
String twentyfive = a.get("foo"); // Return type is String, but the map would contain an Integer.  Run-time exception.
```

Comment: If we cant put any values in the hashmap, then whats the point of having it in the first place ?

Comment: You have to put values in when you know what type you're able to put in.  If it's assigned to a variable with a simple wildcard, you can't add to it through that variable although if you have a reference through a different variable then that's fine.

Comment: How do we use such a hashmap ? cast it to Map<String,Integer> when we know that its integer for sure?

Comment: You can do that, yes.  Most of the time, having to do something like that is a sign of poor design (possibly elsewhere in the system) just like having to store things as then cast them from `Object` is a sign of poor design.  Sometimes the poor design is required due to limitations in Java.